# Show Dates into tableview from api request matches the current month dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdate

I need a little help regarding the calender dates.

I am creating NSDate from current date to month end date once its done i plot these dates on tableview. than i call a API on which i get task for that dates.

I place dates on tableview header and in numberOfRowsInSection i compare calender dates to dates i get in the api request.

So what should happen, if current calender dates matches result from API dates than the current dates section must return the number of rows its match.

Below is my code, its working but its return rows for every section.

```
for (int i =0; i<[self.calenderDates count]; i++) {
        NSString * currentDate = self.calenderDates[i];
        for (int j =0; j<[self.papikerCalender count]; j++) {
            NSString * papikDate = [self.papikerCalender[j] valueForKey:@"strat_date"];
            if ([currentDate isEqualToString:papikDate]) {
                [self.rowData addObject:self.papikerCalender[j]];
                [self.dataDictionay setObject:self.rowData forKey:currentDate];

            }
        }
    }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString * currentDate = self.calenderDates[section];
    NSArray * dicDate = [self.dataDictionay valueForKey:currentDate];
    return [dicDate count];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better practice for NSDate comparison.

You could compare the NSDates as below.

```
if (!([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) && !([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    NSLog(@"date is equal");
} else {
    //Not equal
}
```

**OR**

Convert the NSDate to NSString in below way.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];  //Provide your format

//Optionally for time zone conversions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];

if ([stringFromDate isEqualToString:apiDate]) {
    NSLog(@"date is equal");
}
```

Note: Do debug your code and check all date comparison at if condition to check for issue.

//-----UPDATE----//

for (int i =0; i<[self.calenderDates count]; i++) {
        NSString * currentDate = self.calenderDates[i];
        //self.rowData initialise to store new data for particular current date

```
    for (int j =0; j<[self.papikerCalender count]; j++) {
        NSString * papikDate = [self.papikerCalender[j] valueForKey:@"strat_date"];
        if ([currentDate isEqualToString:papikDate]) {
            [self.rowData addObject:self.papikerCalender[j]];

        }
    }

    //Once all data is added to self.rowData then add it to dictionary
    [self.dataDictionay setObject:self.rowData forKey:currentDate];

}
```

Comment: conversion or comparing is not the problem, the problem is if 1-jan contains 4 task, and 10-jan contains 2 than section having date 1-jan must return 4 row and 10-jan must return 2 rows, similarly the rest. right know when dates match to the current date its return all row to every date match section.

Comment: Nslog the self.dataDictionay after you have set task for all dates. Also share it here

Comment: console response is kinda long. i dont see the attachments options, so i paste it.

Comment: dicdate (null)
dicdate (
        {
        "end_date" = "2015-12-31";
        "end_time" = "19:22:00";
        "start_time" = "19:19:00";
        "strat_date" = "2015-12-31";
        zip = 20010;
    },
        {
        "end_date" = "2015-12-31";
        "end_time" = "19:22:00";
        "start_time" = "19:19:00";
        "strat_date" = "2015-12-31";
        zip = 20010;    },
 
)
dicdate (null)
dicdate (null)

Comment: I don't see any key in provided code but I made some update in your for-loop check out my answer. Also its kinda confusing. Pls share the console output in your question with actual and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`NSCalendar` has a convenient method to compare dates restricted to calendar units.

```
BOOL isInSameMonth = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:date1 toDate:[NSDate date] toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMonth] == NSOrderedSame;
```